# How to check if value exist in list element?

Tags: python

I need to check whether the value, let's say 10.0.0.0/16 exist in a list that is constructed in such way:

```
[{'Type': 'IPV4', 'Value': '216.137.32.0/19'}, {'Type': 'IPV4', 'Value': '13.54.63.128/26'}]
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this in python?

That code below doesn't work for obvious reason... What's the right and efficient way?

```
address = '10.0.0.0/16'
current_ips = [{'Type': 'IPV4', 'Value': '216.137.32.0/19'}, {'Type': 'IPV4', 'Value': '13.54.63.128/26'}]
if address in current_ips:
 print("I've found " + address=  + " in current IPs list")
```

Comment: Compare the value of the `'Value'` key of each dictionary in the list to the address you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace current_ips condition with the following set condition:

```
address = '10.0.0.0/16'
current_ips = [{'Type': 'IPV4', 'Value': '216.137.32.0/19'}, {'Type': 'IPV4', 'Value': '13.54.63.128/26'}]

current_ip_values = set(x['Value'] for x in addresses)

if address in current_ip_values:
    print("I've found " + address  + " in current IPs list")
```

Using a set rather than a list for doing these check allows for constant time lookup, so if you need to check a large number of these ips against a large fixed list of current ips, this would be a more efficient way to do it than relying directly on a list.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing strings with dicts, use either a list comprehension that contains all ip address values:

```
if address in [ip['Value'] for ip in current_ips]:
```

Or, use `any`:

```
if any(ip['Value'] == address for ip in current_ips):
```

Also, you have a syntax error in your print statement, it should be something like:

```
print("I've found " + address + " in current IPs list")
```

Comment: Thank you, MrGeek. That is fully solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
address = '10.0.0.0/16'
current_ips = [{'Type': 'IPV4', 'Value': '216.137.32.0/19'}, {'Type': 'IPV4', 'Value': '13.54.63.128/26'},{'Type': 'IPV4', 'Value': '10.0.0.0/16'}]

for item in current_ips:
    if item['Value'] == address:
        print("I've found {} in current IPs list {}".format(address,item))
```

output:

```
I've found 10.0.0.0/16 in current IPs list {'Type': 'IPV4', 'Value': '10.0.0.0/16'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [ip in L['Value'] for L in l if L['Value'] == ip]
if result:
    print('IP {} was found {} times in list'.format(ip,len(l)))
else:
    print('IP {} was not found in list'.format(ip))
```